# Flatten a tree in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table, called Ancestry that consists of two columns: Parent and Child.   I want to create a View or extract table using sql that represents lineage in two columns: Parent and Dependent.   The Dependent will be a child, grandchild, great grandchild etc.
For example, the Ancestry table contains the following:

```
Parent   Child
A  ------ A.1
A  ------ A.2
A.1 ----- A.1.1
A.1 ----- A.1.2
A.2 ----- A.2.1
A.2 ----- A.2.2  and so on
```

Note these values are purely to illustrate the lineage; actual values, number of children and depth of tree are totally flexible and I have no control over them.

I want my result query to produce:

```
  Parent    Dependent
   null ---- A      (this row may not be possible!)
   A ------- A.1
   A ------- A.2
   A ------- A.1.1
   A ------- A.1.2
   A ------- A.2.1
   A ------- A.2.2
   A.1 ----- A.1.1
   A.1 ----- A.1.2
   A.2 ----- A.2.1
   A.2 ----- A.2.2
```

When I use the following I get siblings also, rather than just direct dependents:

```
select distinct  a.Parent,b.Child from Ancestry  a,Ancestry b
where  concat(a.Parent,b.Child not in (
select concat(a.Child,b.Child) from Ancestry a,Ancestry b
where a.Parent = b.Parent and a.Child <> b.Child)
order by a.Parent,b.Child;
```

I appreciate any alternative approaches also.

Comment: Can there only be one level separating the ancestor and the dependent, or could it theoretically be any number of levels?

Comment: It can be any number of levels and any values - a classic bill of materials problem, except in this case a child can only have one parent, which should simplify it

Comment: It looks like starting with MySQL version 8 this question can finally be given the same answer as for other SQL engines: a recursive CTE query, see  http://mysqltutorial.org/mysql-recursive-cte and especially check **employees example** at http://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=3634

Answer (score 0):

Using your example you could work off the subset of parents names in children should parent names be contained inside dependents' names. If so, consider a union query:

```
# GREAT-GRANDPARNTS
SELECT DISTINCT Null As Parent, Parent As Dependent
FROM Ancestry
WHERE Len(Parent) = 1

UNION

# GRANDPARNTS
SELECT DISTINCT Left(Parent, 1) As Parent, Parent As Dependent
FROM Ancestry
WHERE Len(Parent) = 3

UNION

# PARENTS
SELECT DISTINCT Left(Child, 1) As Parent, Child As Dependent
FROM Ancestry
WHERE Len(Child) > 3

UNION

# CHILDREN
SELECT DISTINCT Left(Child, 3) As Parent, Child As Dependent
FROM Ancestry
WHERE Len(Child) > 3;
```

Of course adjust `Len()` , `Left()`, or `Mid()` string functions and extend (i.e., grandchildren) according to actual Ancestry name patterning. This solution will not work if there is no reference of parents in child string values.

Comment: Solution will be removed should data not align to simplified example.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately I have no control over the values of the parent and children, or the depth of the tree.  The solution needs to be flexible.

Comment: But is parent names contained in child names in any way? Or by looking at both values, one cannot tell they relate?

Answer (score 0):

This may work

```
select p.parent, c.child
from       Ancestry  p
left join  Ancestry  c   on p.parent = left(c.child, len(p.parent))
```

Comment: Thank you.  But it also has dependencies on the naming pattern i.e. length of parent name; this is something that I have no control over.

Comment: can you setup please an sqlfiddle?

Comment: There is no similarity between the sample data and the real data - so solutions can not be dependent on data values or lengths of values (unfortunately); the data I showed is just to simplify the tree concept and make viewing the results easier.

Comment: I'm not familiar with sqlfiddle, but here is the ddl for this little sample if you want to try it out:

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Ancestry (
  Parent VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  Child VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  UNIQUE INDEX `p_c` (`Parent` ASC, `Child` ASC));

Comment: insert into ancestry (Parent,Child) values('a','a.1'),('a','a.2'),('a','a.3'),('a.1','a.1.1'),('a.1','a.1.2'),('a.2','a.2.1'),('a.2','a.2.2');